# Motorcycle Brake Lever - Soft Feel & Long Pull

Tags: brakes, brake-fluid, brake-calipers, kawasaki, master-cylinder

I have a 2008 Kawasaki ER6 / Ninja 650R race bike. Within my class I must use OEM calipers & a OEM master cylinder. These components are also not allowed to be modified.

As the title says, the brake lever has a very soft feel and the lever's travel from zero braking to maximum braking is very long. The brake fluid gets changed regularly and bled often. The calipers and the master cylinder have been recently rebuilt by a qualified technician and the bike has braided hoses.

None of these things have made much of a difference. The braided hoses have been on the bikes since I bought it, but as far as I can tell, they are in perfectly good condition.

What else can I do / check to try and improve this?

Thanks in advance
Willem

Comment: Something definitely not adding up. Have you measured rotor run out?  I would hope to see 0.010” or so in the middle of the rotor.  A large run out would require a whole lot of travel.

Comment: I must be honest, I don't really know. How would I check this? The discs were also replaced if that helps?

Comment: Use a dial indicator with an adjustable holder. Here’s a photo of a car rotor. http://image.superchevy.com/f/175473287+w640+h640+q80+re0+cr1+st0/3-front-rotor-runout.jpg

Comment: While rotor runout would affect brake operation when the bike is moving (you'd feel vibration in the brake lever, and the grip amount may vary as the wheel turns), too much run out will have nothing to do with how the lever feels when the bike is standing still.

Comment: David, fair points.. but. 1) The original question made no mention that the "bike is standing still"  Not one word.   2) He hints that he understands master/slave/brake lines expansion/ bleeding. 3)  He specifically asked "What ELSE can I do...?"   I've seen rotor/ axle/ runout related issues cause excessive slave cylinder travel withOUT accompanying vibration, albeit in automobiles, not a bike.  My suspicion is something is pushing the wheel pistons far apart, causing `the lever's travel from zero braking to maximum braking is very long`, perhaps a wheel bearing, or a mount alignment issue.

Comment: With that said, I do tend to agree with you.  `recently rebuilt by a qualified technician` that's nice.  It would be nice to get some better info from Willem. 1) is this a stationary or bike on the track issue? 2) What is the travel at the end of the brake lever, in inches, when stationary ? 3) Are we talking front or rear brakes? 4) Does the travel change during repeated pulls while the bike is stationary?  After five repeated pulls, what is the travel in inches?   5) Any wheel bearing / brake rotor / slave cylinder mounting or alignment issues?  6) whats the rotor runout in 0.001" inches?

Comment: @zipzit The factors you list in your first comment above could contribute to a long pull, but they'd not be causative of a soft lever once the slop in the system has been taken up. You're certainly correct that more info from the OP would be useful. All in all, some part(s) of both our comments may be correct.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for the delay. Don't have the tool to measure the rotor run out, but as I said the discs are quite new and the problem existed with the previous discs and with these discs from brand new.

Comment: 1) The issue is both on track and when the bike is stationary. 2) The brake lever travels 8cm (3.14961 inches) Compared to 5cm (1.9685 inches) as tested on two other bikes. 3) Front brakes only. The front and rear brakes systems are completely independent of each other. 4) The travel remains the same. Worth noting the travel doesn't get any worse during racing. 5) Nothing I know of, will get the technician to check at the next service.

Is it possible that the master cylinder is the problem despite being rebuilt?

Answer (score 2):

The cause of a soft brake lever is one or more of (a) air in the brake lines, (b) tired brake lines that expand as brake fluid pressure increases when the brake lever is pulled, (c) failing master cylinder, (d) failing wheel cylinder(s), and/or (e) a physical leak in the brake system that yields a puddle on the garage floor and may allow entry of air, causing (a).

(c) and (d) failures may not be evident externally. If the brake fluid level in the master cylinder reservoir isn't going down over time, then the problem is not (e).

You will need to examine the brake system, and rectify any fault(s) you find. Only because it's a very common problem, I'll guess the issue is (a). Find good instructions on how to bleed your machine's brakes, and follow them. You might ask other Ninja pilots how they do the job.

Comment: Hi David, (a) The brakes are bled regularly and not just by myself (b) The brake lines are braided hoses, could they be past it or of an incorrect spec/diameter? There are no visible leaks. (c) the master cylinder was recently rebuilt with new OEM internals, could the master cylinder be so past it that a rebuild would not be sufficient? (d) The calipers were also recently rebuilt, I'm assuming wheel cylinder = calipers. (e) There are no visible leaks and no puddles near the bike.

Comment: If you cannot obtain a hard lever after bleeding, then either you still have air in the system (perhaps trapped at one or more of the wheel calipers), or one or more of the brake lines are expanding under pressure, or the master cylinder piston seal has failed, or the master cylinder bore isn't sealing to the master cylinder piston rubber seal. Do you get clean no-bubble fluid at each caliper when you bleed? I've never heard of braided lines failing, but anything's possible. If the fault is at the master cylinder, I'd replace the entire master cylinder with new.

Comment: No bubbles when bleeding the brakes, I've bled them myself and two mechanics have bled them on separate occasions. I'm considering replacing the master cylinder and changing it to a newer model, perhaps it will give better results. Do you think I should replace the brake lines as well?

Comment: I've never heard of a braided line failing, and have heard many times about master cylinder failure. Thus, I think the fault is more likely to be in the master cylinder. I'd replace it with new, then fill and bleed again.

Answer (score 0):

do you have ABS? if not, it's air, or a damaged worn master cylinder (the pump on the handlebar)

if you have ABS it could be the abs module